# which is your favourite game /what is your favourite game

Tags: which-what

I want to know the difference between *what* and *which*, and between *who* and *which*

For example :

*what* is your favourite game / *which* is your favourite game

Answer (score 2):

When we ask "which is your favorite", we mean "which *of these* is your favorite", while "what is your favorite" can include any and all games, including games the questioner has never even heard of.

The distinction is important, because "which" easily can be used in what is called a "loaded question".  Which is your favorite food, hamburgers or hot dogs? You see that your choice has been limited to two foods, while "What is your favorite food?" could have ten thousand different answers.

Someone could also ask "What is your favorite food, hamburgers or hot dogs?", but the deception would be obvious, because "what" is used generally, and "which" implies "which *of these*".